# When I click reset button or load this page, all the fields are empty

Tags: angularjs

Output image:

[image: output image]

I tried comparing the original code with this but I'm unable to find any mistakes. I'm very confused why this is not working. When page is reloaded or reset button is clicked all fields has to be filled with details but its not happening. What might be the mistake?

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Angular practice</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div ng-app="" ng-controller="studentController">
    <form name="studentForm" novalidate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>first name</td>
            <td><input name="firstname" type="text" ng-model="firstName"       required>
                <span style="color: red;" ng-show="studentForm.firstname.$dirty && studentForm.firstname.$invalid">
                    <span ng-show="studentForm.firstname.$error.required">enter first name</span>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>last name</td>
            <td><input name="lastname" type="text" ng-model="lastName" required>
            <span style="color: red;" ng-show="studentForm.lastname.$dirty && studentForm.lastname.$invalid">
                    <span ng-show="studentForm.lastname.$error.required">enter last name</span>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>email</td>
            <td><input name="email" type="email" ng-model="email" required>
            <span style="color: red;" ng-show="studentForm.email.$dirty && studentForm.email.$invalid">
                    <span ng-show="studentForm.email.$error.required">enter email ID</span>
                    <span ng-show="studentForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email</span>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button></td>
            <td><button ng- disabled="studentForm.firstname.$dirty &&
                                        studentForm.firstname.$invalid ||
                                        studentForm.lastname.$dirty && studentForm.lastname.$invalid||
                                        studentForm.email.$dirty && studentForm.email.$invalid" 
                        ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        function studentController($scope){
            $scope.reset = function(){
                $scope.firstName = "uthej";
                $scope.lastName  = "ks";
                $scope.email     = "uthej@gmail.com";
            }
            $scope.reset();
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you add HTML code also? are you getting any error?

Comment: yes i added the code and output image also..

Comment: in your question app="", app name is missing, check appName & try again.

Comment: but in my previous codes it was working without appName... and in the original code there is no appName

Comment: thank you omprakash sharma its working, but I wonder why previous codes worked without appName...

Comment: It may be in your parent HTML file app="appName" could be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-app is missing in your HTML code and you are not injecting controller in app.

HTML Code

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="studentController">
```

Js code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('studentController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.reset = function () {
        $scope.firstName = "uthej";
        $scope.lastName = "ks";
        $scope.email = "uthej@gmail.com";
    }
    $scope.reset();
});
```

Comment: Would you edit into this a sentence or two about what the problem was? New readers will find that useful to understand how the issue was resolved.

Comment: sure, I'll do that :)

Answer (score 0):

you have misspelled HTML & Script, Correct one is..

Html::

```
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="studentController">
    <form name="studentForm" novalidate>
        // form fields will goes here....
    </form>
</div>
```

& script::

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("demoApp", []);
        app.controller("studentController", function($scope){
            $scope.reset = function(){
                $scope.firstName = "uthej";
                    $scope.lastName  = "ks";
                    $scope.email     = "uthej@gmail.com";
            };$scope.reset();

        });
    </script>
```

I hope it will work for you.